# How to delete merged commit from original repo safely?

Tags: github

I have to delete 2 last commits pushed to original repo, one of which is a merge commit. I want to delete changes in repo and keep them on my computer.
When I do

```
    git revert -m 1  075cc2f
```

It adds a revert commit to my history of commits and my 075cc2f commit is still present there. 
When I do

```
    git push origin +HEAD^:master
```

commit is fully deleted from history.
However, when things come to merged second commit, it is being deleted only with commits of a person who pushed before me. We both had some version "v" at moment of cloning a repo. He pushed his commit to original repo and version of a project became  "v+1". I still had version "v" and merged a project by:

```
    ➜git add .
    ➜git commit -am "My commit»
    ➜git pull  
    subl -w: subl: command not found
    error: There was a problem with the editor 'subl -w'.
    Not committing merge; use 'git commit' to complete the merge.
    ➜git commit -am "My commit»
    ➜git pull  
    Already up-to-date.
    ➜git push -u origin master
```

When I use to a merged commit:

```
    git push origin +HEAD^:master
```

It is being deleted only with commits of a person who pushed before me.
Now I want to delete that merge commit from history fully without deleting other people's pushes.

[There is another way to do this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4T7O.png)

> You could follow these steps to revert the incorrect commit(s) or to reset your remote branch back to correct HEAD/state.
>
> 1. checkout the remote branch to local repo.
>      `git checkout development`
> 2. copy the commit hash (i.e. id of the commit immediately before the wrong commit) from git log
>      `git log -n5`
>
>    > output:
>    >
>    > commit 7cd42475d6f95f5896b6f02e902efab0b70e8038 "Merge branch 'wrong-> > > commit' into 'development'" 
>    >     commit f9a734f8f44b0b37ccea769b9a2fd774c0f0c012 "this is a wrong commit" > 
>    >     commit 3779ab50e72908da92d2cfcd72256d7a09f446ba "this is the correct > > > commit"
> 3. reset the branch to the commit hash copied in the previous step 
>      `git reset <commit-hash> (i.e. 3779ab50e72908da92d2cfcd72256d7a09f446ba)`
> 4. run the `git status` to show all the changes that were part of the > > wrong commit.
> 5. simply run `git reset --hard` to revert all those changes.
> 6. force-push your local branch to remote and notice that your commit > > history is clean as it was before it got polluted.
>      `git push -f origin development`

[process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lYvR.png)

But again it deletes not only merged commit, but also his parent

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJHyJ.png)
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmpin.png)

```
       commit b142e1ed9 has 2 parents f4cc23a + 2537c51
```

Comment: Do you really _need_ to completely remove the two commits from history?  If not, then `git revert` is the safe way to go here.

Comment: I really need to delete fully, so no one can see some conf. info there.

Comment: You're a bit stuck then.  You have already pushed that info to GitHub, and others may have already pulled.  If you _must_ remove it, then you will have to something like an interactive rebase.  And it gets tricky because one of the commits is a merge commit.

Comment: Thank you, I  solved problem using interactive rebase